# iPhone voicemail notice outside cellular service, but no msg when in service area?

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I am often in remote areas without cellular service. I do get wireless connection, and every so often my iPhone4S (iOS9.3.5) displays a notification on my phone service (the red dot without a number):

[image]  [image]

When I get to a cell service area, however, there is no message.

Is this red dot indicating a voice message has arrived?

Is the notice a mistake?

Has an actual voice message been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought the red dot without a number means your Voicemail service is unavailable, not that you have Voicemail waiting.

I spend a lot of my time outside reception areas, or abroad with no roaming, & I have that icon the entire time I'm away; whether or not I have voicemail waiting for me when I get back [usually I don't].

Comment: Ah - that certainly would explain it!

Comment: I have no concrete evidence, only my own anecdotal - but that certainly does seem to have been the case.

Comment: I'm googling for confirmation... found this which seems promising (I did recently switch SIMs...?) http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/23/blank-red-dot-phone-icon-iphone/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen many similar articles - though none that can simply repro what I see when I'm completely 'out of range'

Comment: Will be in cel range later today and check then. Thanks!

Comment: Wish you luck :)

Comment: Well... Backin cel range... No red dot. I looked in the ios9 and my 4s manuals but no mention of this "feature" and i cant find anything from apple about it.